# systemd shutdown what does -h mean when combined with --halt?

Tags: linux, shutdown, systemd

the systemd shutdown documentation at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html says that `-h` changes meaning when combined with `--halt`, but it doesn't elaborate, so what does `-h` mean when combined with `--halt` ? what is the difference between `shutdown --halt` and `shutdown --halt -h` ? quote

> ```
>   -h
>       Equivalent to --poweroff, **unless --halt is specified.**
>   -H, --halt
>       Halt the machine.
>   -P, --poweroff
>       Power-off the machine (the default).
> ```

edit: i've complained about the lack of documentation on the systemd bugtracker: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/23401

Comment: This flag probably only exists for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

"Halt" was the original operation; it would stop the OS, but wouldn't turn off power, as most computers at the time didn't even have soft power-off. After such an ability was added to PCs, however, in most sysvinit configurations "halt" became equivalent to "poweroff", i.e. running `halt` or `shutdown -h` would actually turn off the whole system.

With systemd the two operations became separate again, so using `halt` performs most of the shutdown process but leaves the machine *powered on,* although completely unresponsive (just sitting at the "`System halted.`" kernel message). To perform a normal shutdown you need to use `poweroff` command.

But to retain *some* compatibility with programs (or fingers) which might have been hardcoded to run `shutdown -h` to power the machine down, systemd's version of 'shutdown' will actually send a `PowerOff()` call to systemd, rather than a `Halt()` call, when the `-h` option is used.

tl;dr: `shutdown -h` will ask systemd to "power off", *not* to "halt", but `shutdown -h --halt` will in fact ask it to "halt" the system without powering off.